# I'm trying to populate my tableview with data from the Firebase Realtime database

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database

I can load my current tableview data onto the database and then print out the new data onto my console but can't get the new data back into the tableview and I'm tearing my hair out because I know it should be simple!

I've tried all sorts of things but I just can't figure out where I'm going wrong.

```
//Saves to database without any problems
//Class
var ref: DatabaseReference!
//ViewDidLoad
ref = Database.database().reference()

func save()
{
let ref = Database.database().reference(withPath: "Admin")

let adding = ref.child(me)

let addData: [String: [String]] = ["addJokes": data]

adding.setValue(addData)
{
    (error:Error?, ref:DatabaseReference) in
    if let error = error
    {
        print("Data could not be saved: \(error).")
    }
    else
    {
        print("Data saved successfully!")
    }
}
}
```

Can print out the database data to my console but can't get it into my tableview

```
let ref = Database.database().reference(withPath: "Admin")

    ref.observe(.value, with:
        {
            (snapshot) in

            let new = snapshot.value as? String

            print(snapshot.value as Any)

            if let newData = new
            {
                self.data.append(newData)
                self.mainTable.reloadData()
            }
    })
```

### Update

TableView details-

TableView Class Ext

```
extension TableView: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate

{

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        if isSearching {
             return filteredArray.count
        }
        else
        {
            return data.count
        }
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        var array: String?
        if isSearching
        {
            array = filteredArray[indexPath.row]
        }
        else
        {
            array = data[indexPath.row]
        }
        let cell = mainTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
      cell.textLabel?.text = array
        return cell
    }
```

TableView Class-

```
class TableView: UIViewController

{

    let cellId = "cellId"

    var filteredArray = [String]()

    var ref: DatabaseReference!

    var data = [

        """
       multiple line 
       data array
        """
       ]

    lazy var mainTable: UITableView =
        {
            let table = UITableView()
            table.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            table.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellId)
            return table
    }()
        override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        mainTable.delegate = self
        mainTable.dataSource = self
}
```

Console prints exactly what I want back into my tableview. Turning print function into results is usually the easy part.

Comment: Please share your tableView code

Comment: Please, try this `DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self. mainTable.reloadData()
}` and see any `UITableViewDelegate` methods are called.

Comment: What is the database structure? and provide code from the tableview delegate methods

Comment: minhazur, I tried DispatchQueue.main.async { self. mainTable.reloadData() } but nothing was called. Database path is direct which prints to my console exactly the same way that it is entered into the array. I do see Optional(<__NSArrayM 0x2800e7a80>( before the data which I'm going to look into after dinner.

Comment: Can you please, add code of the class responsible for managing `UITableView`? Need to check `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` delegate methods implementation.

Comment: Both self, not sure if that's causing problems? I wonder if the optional NSArray message printed on the console is the issue?

Comment: I think the problem lies in `let new = snapshot.value as? String`. Please, print `new` and see whether it's null or not, if null `if let newData = new` will be false and if block won't be executed.

Comment: Thanks minhazur! That was it. solution is- let new = (snapshot.value)
                self.data = new as! [String]

Comment: great :) ... let me pul it on the answer section, so others can get the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in `let new = snapshot.value as? String`. Here, `new` is null thus `if let newData = new` is always false and if block won't be executed. First, check `snapshot.value`'s data type and value then use it accordingly.